# Visual Studio 2012 - Generate .dll.refresh files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, add-references-dialog

We recently started using Visual Studio **2012**. We are also using third party ASP.NET controls from DevExpress. We are also using Team Foundation Server 2012.

For simplicity let's say the folder structure looks something like this:

```
C:\Tfs\Main\Components

C:\Tfs\Main\WebSite
```

In the past, when we added a reference to a third party DLL, the procedure was:

Add the actual DLLs to the /Components folder

Add *.dll.refresh files to the /WebSite/bin folder

I am trying to do that in Visual Studio 2012, however ...

Each time I select 'Add Reference' and **Browse** (I am actually browsing to the DLL file ... not selecting another Project) to the /Components folders -

(1) The DevExpress components appear to be added as **GAC** type references
(2) The DLLs are *not* copied to the /bin folder
(3) No .dll.refresh files are being created

The problem is ... when I check-in and another Developer does a 'get latest', if he doesn't have DevExpress installed then this will cause a problem.

So what am I missing?

Why won't Visual Studio 2012 create the .dll.refresh files in the /bin folder for me?

Thank you,

Glen J Fergo

Answer (score 2):

Make your dll's solution items and reference them from there.